# Consistency of HASH function

Tags: google-bigquery

A pretty simple question: which version of CityHash is hidden behind the `HASH` function of BigQuery? Is it always the latest (today v1.1), or rather a fixed version?

Now, a little bit of backgroud. I plan on relying heavily upon BigQuery to store large sets of data. From those data, in a first time, I would like to compute some hash value and store it (something like `hashed_value = HASH(CONCAT(column_0, column_1))`). So far so good.
In a second time, I would like to retrieve rows with a given hash value with a request such as `SELECT something FROM [mytable] WHERE hashed_value = HASH(CONCAT('12345', 'foobar'))`.
My concern here is that it is specified on the CityHash webpage that those functions are not supposed to be backward compatible. So that if BigQuery relies always on the **latest** version of CityHash, I will not be able to retrieve my data based on the hash value of some computed columns after the next CityHash update. And for my application my large database will essentially become useless.

If so, would it be possible to give access to a fixed (or backward-compatible) hash function, in addition to `HASH` ? One on the `SHA`, `MD` and so on for exemple, or even a fixed version of CityHash.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

CityHash used in BigQuery is the version from 
http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/
Looking at the history, it seems like the value can change over time. This might be a good question for:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/cityhash-discuss

BigQuery should support a consistent hash. We do have support for sha1, but right now the result is unusable because of encoding issues. You can, however, do `SELECT TO_BASE64(SHA1(CONCAT('12345', 'foobar')))`

Note that we will likely change `SHA1` in the near future to automatically base64 encode the results. I've filed an internal bug to make this change.

Comment: Oh! That's great. But did I miss a discrete reference to `SHA1` (or `TO_BASE64`) in the BigQuery [reference manual](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference)? Or are they just hidden features? If so, would it be possible to get a list of those hidden statements?

Comment: No, there wasn't a reference to either sha1 or to_base64 in our docs. These are 'not-yet-documented' and therefore 'use at your own risk'. Some 'hidden' statements may be features we're testing out before releasing publicly. Some of them we just haven't gotten around to documenting yet.

Comment: what BigQuery record type would you recommend for storing 160-bit hash values?  Is there a secret binary data type for that?

Comment: Are there plans on getting `sha1` to work without the encoding step?

Comment: `SHA1` now returns the recently-added `BYTES` type, and should be usable without the encoding step.