# CHAR() or ASCII() function in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any version of this in BigQuery?

Basically I need to take a BASE64 letter and convert it to a numeric value consistently (to BASE64 index or to ASCII - no difference for me).

So far I've invented 2 options:
- to use UDF
- to JOIN a table with all 64 letters and indexes.

But both solutions look a bit too complicated for the task. Is there any better way?

Comment: can you show off your `inventions`? so it is more clear what you are trying to achieve. also would be great to see why you need this - there is always another way to do thing simpler!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option to convert letter to its ASCII with BigQuery:

```
SELECT 
  char, 
  INSTR('@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', char)
   + 63 AS ascii
FROM 
  (SELECT 'A' AS char),
  (SELECT 'H' AS char),
  (SELECT 'a' AS char),
  (SELECT 'h' AS char)
```

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant! Thank you very much! I'm trying to split "users" into 2 or more groups randomly. User ids are unique but not really random, so I wanted to do SHA1(user_id) first, then take the first letter, convert to number and take mod 2. Could use HASH() of course, but I need to do the same in a different place (and in ruby), and I couldn't get same CityHash results there, also read here consistency is not guaranteed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861380/consistency-of-hash-function

Comment: glad it helped :o)

Answer (score 2):

There *is* the equivalent of an ASCII function in BigQuery, but you need to construct it from `to_code_points()`:

```
select to_code_points(substr(x, 1, 1))[offset(0)]
```

`to_code_points` returns the character set values for a string as an array.  This construct takes the first character of a string, gets the values in an array, and then returns the first value in the array -- Voila!  `ASCII()`.

Comment: Would this work without the `substr` call? I.e. just `to_code_points(x)[offset(0)]`? Or is the `substr` call there just for efficiency?