# Is there a way to seed the random number generation process in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have used the LegacySQL `rand()` function ([found here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#rand)) before which takes an integer as an argument for seeding the random number generation process.

When I started using the same `rand()` function in StandardSQL ([found here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rand)), it does not allow me to provide a seed. So my question is if I want do some seeding when generating number, is there a way to do it in StandardSQL in BigQuery?

This is important because in scientific research sometimes we need to deal with random numbers but also the results need to be reproducible.

Comment: Could you describe your scenario why you need rand() with a seed?

Comment: In my research I am sampling from a large pool of data. Seeding is a nice way to make sure my research is reproducible and debugging the sampling process.

Comment: Please try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019624/how-to-do-repeatable-sampling-in-bigquery-standard-sql . I also provided an answer and some discussion about different scenario, please upvote if you find helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to provide a seed into the [`RAND()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rand) function in the standard SQL language. In [this public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905709) you can see that the integer types created a problematic scenario in the `RAND()` function. These issues were corrected in standard SQL and, as a consequence, some built-in functions were modified.

Answer (score 4):

As the above answer states, No, but you may be able to do something similar with a hash function such as *sha256*, *sha1* or *md5*.

I use this to sort my output into a random order that is the same every time.

Comment: nice out of the box thinking man!