# Set random seed in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've seen these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545915/is-there-a-way-to-seed-the-random-number-generation-process-in-bigquery-standard) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019624/how-to-do-repeatable-sampling-in-bigquery-standard-sql?noredirect=1&lq=1) mention the same issue. The answers are almost an year old, and wondering if any more updates were given in BQ - I could not find any concrete answers in the documentation.

I'm trying to do repeated sampling and would like consistent results. This is important for me.

The solution provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019624/how-to-do-repeatable-sampling-in-bigquery-standard-sql?noredirect=1&lq=1), does not provide consistent results.

Here is my code

```
SELECT 
*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as incremental_number
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            Table1 as cmd
        WHERE 
            Member NOT IN (
                    SELECT 
                        Member
                    FROM 
                        table2
                    WHERE 
                        Idx = ‘6’
                    )
        ) as t
    WHERE
        MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(t))), 10) < 5
    )

ORDER BY Member
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just the order of rows is different? Try to sort them.

Comment: Try to sort inside `OVER()`

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x)